# AppendMenu doesn't work when ModalPopupMode=pmAuto

Tags: delphi, forms, popup, modal-dialog

In Delphi, i use the following line (and others, almost identical) to add items to the system menu of forms:

```
AppendMenu(GetSystemMenu(Self.Handle, False), MF_BYPOSITION, cSetScreenResolution1024x768,  PChar('1024x768'));
```

This is part of a class that all other forms inherit from, and it works fine most of the time, but I've noticed that when forms are opened in modal mode the custom menuitems aren't there. When the same form is opened in modeless mode it works just fine. I've spent some time figuring out why, and I have found that if **ModalPopupMode=pmAuto** I get this error. When it's **pmNone**, things work just fine.

Can anyone explain why this happens? And maybe give advise on how to solve it? I use ModalPopupMode=pmAuto to fix other issues, so it's not a good alternative to revert it to pmNone.

To reproduce, just make a small project with two forms. Drop two buttons on the first form, one to open the second form modally, one to open it modeless. Put this line into the second form's create:

```
AppendMenu(GetSystemMenu(Self.Handle, False), MF_BYPOSITION, 10000,  PChar('1024x768'));
```

It will now work as expected. Now set the applications ModalPopupMode to pmAuto, and observe that the extra menuitem on the systemmenu has disappeared when opening the form modally.

Alternatively (and maybe more conveniently?) copy these 5 "files":

PROJECT1.DPR

```
program Project1;

uses
  Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1},
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.ModalPopupMode := pmAuto;
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

UNIT1.PAS

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses Unit2;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TForm2.Create(nil) do
  try
    ShowModal;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TForm2.Create(Application.Mainform) do
  begin
    show;
  end;
end;

end.
```

UNIT1.DFM

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 337
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Modal'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object Button2: TButton
    Left = 8
    Top = 39
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Modeless'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = Button2Click
  end
end
```

UNIT2.PAS

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AppendMenu(GetSystemMenu(Self.Handle, False), MF_BYPOSITION, 10000,  PChar('Test'));
end;

end.
```

UNIT2.DFM

```
object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form2'
  ClientHeight = 337
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor is not the place to manipulate a form's window handle. A control's handle may get re-created during the lifetime of the form.

You should only use the window handle after you know the form *has* a window handle. Override your form's `CreateWnd` method and put your `AppendMenu` code there. That method is called after the form's handle has been created, *each* time the form's handle is created, so you may see it called multiple times for the same form. Some property of your form is probably changing while it's being created modally, and that's causing the window to be re-created. In fact, your `AppendMenu` command might be exacerbating the problem by forcing the form to create its window before it's ready. (Reading the `Handle` property forces the handle into existence if it's not already there.)

Comment: `TCustomForm.ShowModal` has got a call to `RecreateWnd` depending on the 'PopupMode' of the Form and 'ModalPopupMode' of the Application.

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of this. Thanks Sertac also.